# How can I send Mat(opencv) via UDP

Tags: opencv, udp, video-streaming

I'm coding a program for making a video call using java and openCV. I am trying to send "Mat" in openCV via UDP.

My code :

```
public class Test_2503_video {
static int check_fps = 0;
static NewJFrame frame_to_show = new NewJFrame();
public static void main (String args[]){
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);
    frame_to_show.setVisible(true);
    DatagramSocket datagramSocket = null;
    try {
        datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(1995);
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test_2503_video.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    if(!camera.isOpened()){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    else {
        Mat frame = new Mat();
            BufferedImage bf = null;
            fps();
        while(true){
            if (camera.read(frame)){
                    bf = Mat2BufferedImage(frame);
                    Icon icon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(bf).getImage().getScaledInstance(frame.width(), frame.height(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
                    System.out.println(frame.total()*frame.channels());
                    byte[] bs = new byte[10240];
                    frame.get(0, 0, bs);
                        try {
                            DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(bs, bs.length,InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"),1996);
                            datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);
                        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Test_2503_video.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Test_2503_video.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    frame_to_show.video.setIcon(icon);
                check_fps++;
            }
        }   
    }
    camera.release();
}
public static void fps(){
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        while(true){
            frame_to_show.fps.setText(String.valueOf("FPS: "+check_fps));
            check_fps = 0;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Test_2503_video.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
public static BufferedImage Mat2BufferedImage(Mat m)
{

    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
    if (m.channels() > 1)
    {
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
    }
    int bufferSize = m.channels() * m.cols() * m.rows();
    byte[] b = new byte[bufferSize];
    m.get(0, 0, b); // get all the pixels
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(m.cols(), m.rows(), type);
    final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);
    return img;


}
}
```

Provided data element number (10240) should be multiple of the Mat channels count (3).

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this a question about how to allocate an array of bytes of appropriate size? As in `byte[] bs = new byte[frame.total()*frame.channels()];` ?

Comment: Hi  Dan Mašek, thanks for the answer. I've tried it, but received an error message "The message is larger than the maximum supported by the underlying transport: Datagram send failed"

Comment: So that means you need to split the frame data into a number of smaller chunks and send each chunk individually. Then on client you need to provide a mechanism to reassemble the frame back from the chunks. Keep in mind this is UDP (what are the features of this protocol, and therefore what is it that you need to account for).

Comment: If the network has problems, the packets arrive out of order, then resolve how

Comment: You don't need to only send the image chunk in each packet. Imagine this - you have a 10 page document on paper. What would you write on each page to make sure anyone can easily put the pages in order and identify if any page is missing? What else would you add when there is more than 1 document and you want to know which page belongs to which document?